# android, add multiple ImageViews onTouch event

Tags: android, touch-event, dynamically-generated

I've just started programming for Android. I've searched for my problem a lot, but the advises didn't help me. I want the same images appear on screen in the touch coordinates. That's what I've done:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View main_view = (View)findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    main_view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            //ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.broken);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.broken);
            image.setX(event.getX() + image.getWidth() / 2);
            image.setY(event.getY() - image.getHeight() / 2);
            LinearLayout top_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
            LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            image.setLayoutParams(p);
            top_layout.addView(image);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything seems right to me, but when touching the screen, nothing happens. Where is the obvious mistake I've made? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());` you should use the Activity context - `ImageView image = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);` - where MyActivity is the name of your Activity class.

Comment: remove setX and setY lines from your code and try again.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have any invisible root views in your xml layout file ?

Comment: Simon, nothing has changed after changing just the Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a `LinearLayout`.
Let's use a `FrameLayout` instead.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private FrameLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
        mLayout.setOnTouchListener(mListener);

    }

    private OnTouchListener mListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // decode the resource to get width and height
                Options opts = new Options();
                opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, opts);

                int imageWidth = opts.outWidth;
                int imageHeight = opts.outHeight;

                // set the imageview's top and left margins
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageHeight);
                lp.leftMargin = (int) (event.getX() - (imageWidth / 2));
                lp.topMargin = (int) (event.getY() - (imageHeight / 2));

                ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                mLayout.addView(image, lp);

                return false;

            }
            return false;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Benito, thank you a lot. It works fine. The only thing (in my opinion), it's not very good-styled =) I'd put OnTouchListener into the different class

Answer (score 0):

setX and setY don't set the images position.  It basically scrolls the image in place.  The position is controlled by its parent view.  Since its parent is a linear layout, it will always be placed below or to the right of the thing above it in the layout.  If you want to place it somewhere exactly, you need to put it in a parent that supports that, such as the deprecated AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: I agree practically with everything, except the first statement. If we look into the documentation:
"public void setX (float x); Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels"
However, the reason is LinearLayout. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the position its talking about.  Its poorly written documentation I agree.  But the entire point of the view hierarchy system is that you NEVER care about the absolute x and y positions.  The x and y that function refers to is not the x and y relative to screen or parent, because the view doesn't know how to calculate that. Sorry, you're misinterpreting the (bad) documentation.

Comment: Also, read the full description below "This is equivalent to setting the translationX property to be the difference between the x value passed in and the current left property."   It has to do with the x offset of its contents, not the position of the view.